# All data from first table is not showing proper data in sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to add two tables, in which first table contains all the video details, and in second table details of video seen by the user with user_id and video_id. I just want to add both the tables and it will show all the list of videos from first table but if the video is seen by the user, status will show 1 else 1.

Here is my query,

```
SELECT
    videos.id, videos.lang_id, videos.medical_type_id, videos.name, 
    videos.description, videos.thumbnail, videos.video, videos.video_type, 
    videos.delete_status, 
    CASE 
       WHEN video_quews.user_id = $user_id 
          THEN $user_id 
          ELSE 'ok' 
    END AS user_id, 
    video_quews.video_id, video_quews.created_at, 
    CASE 
       WHEN video_quews.video_id = videos.id 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
    END AS status 
FROM
    videos 
LEFT JOIN 
    video_quews ON videos.id = video_quews.video_id 
ORDER BY   
    video_quews.video_id DESC
```

Currently, videos are repeating.

Please help me out

here is my response,

```
{
    "message": "All related videos",
    "status": "success",
    "code": 200,
    "videos": [
        {
            "id": "30",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "15",
            "name": "Fracture",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579869167.png",
            "video": "videos/fracture.m4v",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "6",
            "video_id": "30",
            "created_at": "2021-03-04 23:29:50",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "16",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "14",
            "name": "Electrocution",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698529.png",
            "video": "videos/ELECTROCUTION.m4v",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": "16",
            "created_at": "2021-03-05 08:19:29",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "15",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "13",
            "name": "Adult CPR & AED(Cardiac Arrest)",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698505.png",
            "video": "videos/CPR1.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": "15",
            "created_at": "2021-03-05 08:18:38",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "14",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "12",
            "name": "Choking",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698405.png",
            "video": "videos/Choking.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": "14",
            "created_at": "2021-03-05 08:17:47",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "13",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "11",
            "name": "Chest pain",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698381.png",
            "video": "videos/CHESTPAIN.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": "13",
            "created_at": "2021-03-05 08:17:20",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "12",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "10",
            "name": "Burns",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698360.png",
            "video": "videos/Burns.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": "12",
            "created_at": "2021-03-05 08:16:39",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "11",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "9",
            "name": "Breathing Difficulties",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698344.png",
            "video": "videos/BreathingDifficulties.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": "11",
            "created_at": "2021-03-05 08:16:19",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "6",
            "name": "Asthma",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698286.png",
            "video": "videos/ASTHMA.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": "8",
            "created_at": "2021-03-05 08:15:59",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "24",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "22",
            "name": "Fits/Seizures",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698775.png",
            "video": "videos/SEIZURES.m4v",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "26",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "24",
            "name": "Sprain, strain",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698853.png",
            "video": "videos/SPRAIN&STRAIN.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "28",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "26",
            "name": "Disposing Glove",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698903.png",
            "video": "videos/disposingglove.mp4",
            "video_type": "1",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "31",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "8",
            "name": "Bleeding",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1581498917.png",
            "video": "videos/bleeding.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "18",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "16",
            "name": "Gunshot Wound",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698550.png",
            "video": "videos/Gunshot.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "20",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "18",
            "name": "Hypoglycemia",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698684.png",
            "video": "videos/Hypoglycemia.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "22",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "20",
            "name": "Nose Bleeding",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698728.png",
            "video": "videos/nosebleeding.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "25",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "23",
            "name": "Snake Bite",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698801.png",
            "video": "videos/SnakeBite.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "27",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "25",
            "name": "Stroke",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698879.png",
            "video": "videos/STROKE.m4v",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "29",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "27",
            "name": "Dog Bite",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698934.png",
            "video": "videos/Dogbite.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "32",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "7",
            "name": "Allergy",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1581580973.png",
            "video": "videos/Allergy.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "19",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "17",
            "name": "Hyperthermia(Heat Exhaustion)",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698575.png",
            "video": "videos/Hyperthermia.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "21",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "19",
            "name": "Introduction",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698707.png",
            "video": "videos/intro.mp4",
            "video_type": "1",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "23",
            "lang_id": "2",
            "medical_type_id": "21",
            "name": "Recovery Position",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail_images/1579698747.png",
            "video": "videos/RecoveryPosition.mp4",
            "video_type": "2",
            "delete_status": "1",
            "user_id": "ok",
            "video_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "status": "0"
        }
    ],
}
```

Below is my database,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV9Gs.png)

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: yes, it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to add both the tables and it will show all the list of videos from first table but if the video is seen by the user, status will show 1 else 1.

I think you want a flag indicating if a user has seen a video.  For this, I suggest `EXISTS`:

```
select v.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from video_quews vq
                          where v.id = vq.video_id and vq.user_id = $user_id 
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as has_user_flag
from videos v
```

Comment: @Bhawesh . . . Yes.  I'm not bothering to list out the columns in `videos` because it is not relevant to your question.